# How to combine elements of 3 lists or more two by two in python?

Tags: python, combinations

Given 3 or more lists, how to combine their elements two by two in an elegant pythonic way.

what i have tried (which works) so far:

```
list_a =[1,2,3]
list_b=["a","b","c"]
list_c = [0.1,0.2]
list_lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

results = []
for i in range(len(list_lists)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list_lists)):
        results = results + [(x,y) for x in list_lists[i] for y in list_lists[j]] 
print(results)
```

Which produces:

```py
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (2, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.1), (3, 0.2), ('a', 0.1), ('a', 0.2), ('b', 0.1), ('b', 0.2), ('c', 0.1), ('c', 0.2)]
```

If we can do it like : `list(itertools.combinations(*list_lists,2))`, it will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: ibra, can you add your expected output please?

Comment: Just edited the question, but its `[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (2, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.1), (3, 0.2), ('a', 0.1), ('a', 0.2), ('b', 0.1), ('b', 0.2), ('c', 0.1), ('c', 0.2)]`

Answer (score 3):

Looking for something like this?

```
import itertools

list_a =[1,2,3]
list_b=["a","b","c"]
list_c = [0.1,0.2]
list_lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

results = []
for pair in itertools.combinations(list_lists, 2):
    results.extend(itertools.product(*pair))
print(results)
```

We get every pair of lists and add the Cartesian product of the two lists to `results`.

Comment: Very nice, thank you, . `combined = itertools.combinations(list_lists, 2)` and `print(*combined)`, this gives `([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) ([1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2]) (['a', 'b', 'c'], [0.1, 0.2])`, the question now is: in the combination we have only address (ref) of the combined lists, or the lists them self are copied, and hence redundancy, and space memory problem.

Answer (score 1):

First combine the lists two by two and for each list pair, get the product of their elements.  You can do this in a list comprehension:

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = ["a","b","c"]
list_c = [0.1,0.2]
list_lists = [list_a, list_b, list_c]

from itertools import combinations,product
result = [ pair for listPair in combinations(list_lists,2)
                for pair in product(*listPair)]

print(result)
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), 
 (3, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.2), (2, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.1), 
 (3, 0.2), ('a', 0.1), ('a', 0.2), ('b', 0.1), ('b', 0.2), ('c', 0.1), 
 ('c', 0.2)]
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you, . `combined = itertools.combinations(list_lists, 2)` and `print(*combined)`, this gives `([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) ([1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2]) (['a', 'b', 'c'], [0.1, 0.2])`, the question now is: in the combination we have only address (ref) of the combined lists, or the lists them self are copied, and hence redundancy, and space memory problem.

Comment: I wrote it as a list but, if you change the brackets `result = [ ... ]` to parentheses `result = ( ... )` it will be a generator which you can use to iterate (using a for loop) without consuming extra memory.

Comment: Thank you @Alain T for your response. I am not asking about the final result, in my case it should be in a list, son `result = [ ... ]` is ok for me. my question : since I am beginner in python, i don't know if `combinations(list_lists,2)` return the combinations of only the reference (or address) of the lists, or it copy them and return their combinations . If `res = combinations(list_lists,2)` and `print(*res)` we get `([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) ([1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2]) (['a', 'b', 'c'], [0.1, 0.2])`, it seems that the list are copied and hence redundancy.

Comment: combinations() returns tuples which are immutable objects (so not references). The content of the tuples are copies of the originals so `combinations(list_lists,2)` produces tuples containing "references" to the 2 lists in each pairs.  But since this is then fed into product() you get copies of the list elements in the final tuples.  In short `combinations(list_lists,2)` does not duplicate the lists but `product()` duplicates the values.